# What is the JQL for finding issues that have children in a particular JIRA Structure?

Tags: jira

I want to find all the JIRA issues in a particular Structure that have child items. Is there a JQL to do this? I'm familiar with general JQL but the Structure plugin is new to me.

I found the [JQL reference for Structure](https://wiki.almworks.com/display/structure/S-JQL+Reference) but I am totally lost in how to create the right JQL incantation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out:

```
issue in structure("MY STRUCTURE NAME", "not leaf")
```